# UWP - cannot deserialize class - but in WPF works

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, datacontractserializer

I have the following snippet in PCL:

```
public void Save(Stream s)
{
     var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
     serializer.WriteObject(stream, someMyClassInstance);
}

public void Load(Stream s)
{
     var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
     var myInstance = (MyClass)serializer.ReadObject(stream)
}
```

In WPF there is no problem with this code:

```
using (var str = File.OpenWrite("file.txt"))
{
    Save(str);
}

using (var str = File.OpenRead("file.txt"))
{
    Load(str);
}
```

Object is serialized and deserialized properly.

But in Universal app:

```
StorageFile storageFile = /* got from picker */

using (var st = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    Save(st);
}

StorageFile readStorageFile = /* got from picker */

using (var st = await readStorageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    Load(st);
}
```

I got classic deserialization exception - "Invalid char at position 1 1".
What is wrong? Is it about encoding? I cannot set explicit encoding anywhere in UWP for stream. What can I do?

Comment: So, is this XML, JSON? something with a verifiable correct/incorrect format?  It might be worth looking at the difference in what's written to disk to really understand what might be going on.

Comment: It is XML. When I read stream directly to string, it looks as valid. I have tried to read all to string, then create XmlReader from that string but the same errors occurs

Comment: The next thing to try is to isolate if the problem is on serialization vs. deserialization.  Assuming the class you want to serialize is in a portable library, serialize it using the full .NET, then serialize the same object with a new name using .Net Core (UWP).  The next step is to deserialize the stream into the opposite platform.  If the full .NET platform chokes on the stream then the problem is probably on the serialization side.  If the .Net Core platform doesn't choke, you've confirmed it.  If it does choke, you have issues on both sides.